# Bootstrap 4 Nested Collapse Style Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

there is a collapse (with button 2) inside of a another collaspe (with button 1).
when parent is collapsed the background color of button 1 is blue (bg- primary) and when its not collapsed the backpround color is yellow (bg- warning). when we click button 2, the color stays yellow but when button 2 clicked again and its collapsed, the color of button 1 changes to blue. I want to button 1 stays yellow when it is not collapsed whether her child is collapsed or not.

thank you and sorry for my bad english.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="my-2">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn1" type="button" name="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsebtn" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsebtn">
          button 1
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse" id="collapsebtn">
      <div class="mb-2">
        <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" type="button" name="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsebtn2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsebtn2">
            button 2
          </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse border border-primary" id="collapsebtn2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor text....
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#collapsebtn").on("show.bs.collapse", function() {
        $("#btn1").removeClass("btn-primary");
        $("#btn1").addClass("btn-warning");
      });

      $("#collapsebtn").on("hidden.bs.collapse", function() {
        $("#btn1").addClass("btn-primary");
        $("#btn1").removeClass("btn-warning");
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code:

```
 $("#collapsebtn").on("hidden.bs.collapse", function() {

  if(!$('#collapsebtn').hasClass('show')){

    $("#btn1").addClass("btn-primary");
    $("#btn1").removeClass("btn-warning");

    }
  });
```